# Transformation/transition effects don't work when placed in css file

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with transition effects and noticed that unless i actually place the code in the html page itself they don't work.

My transformation effect below:

Style

```
.test_style:hover {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.6);
    transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

So when i place the code in style.css and link to it:

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This is in my  element so it loads at beginning.
It doesn't actually apply the effect.

If i place the style code directly in the  element then it works without any problems or glitches.

Is there something i am missing?

Comment: have you other stylesheet links in your page? if so, its probably because these stylesheets override styles of their own  on your element

Comment: ah i checked, only one other there and there are no conflicts

Comment: did you add !important at the end of each style inside `.test_style:hover`?

Comment: yes tried !important as well with no luck

Comment: Can you see this specific css file in your dev-tools in the network panel? Is it loading correctly?

May you deliver us a working example with full HTML-code? Maybe you missed something else? Full css code would be fine too.

Are you using scss or less?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried this out locally.

I have two files, both in same folder:

- test.html
- test.css

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="de">
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test_style">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.test_style {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    opacity: .3;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.test_style:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.6);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.6);
    transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

It is working like a charm. Don't know what you are doing wrong, but it is working!

Comment: That is almost exactly what I have. Almost word for word (the skeleton version). Still no luck. When i moved the .test_style:hover to html page then it worked fine.

Comment: - What Browser version are you testing in? 
- Are you testing locally or on a server? 
- If testing on a server, do you have https or http?
- If testing locally, do you have apache or nginx running in background, or are u serving files via file://-protocoll?
- What encodings have your files? Is it utf-8 without BOM? 

I can not think about other problems, yet.

Comment: its dev and using http only. No services that can affect the transition effect. Chrome v50, FF v46, Edge v25

Comment: Sry, but it NEEDS to be your fault and you have not commited any further code or details. Solution is above. We can't help you further I assume

Comment: Needs to be my fault? That's a bit silly, as it indicates I am purposefully trying to sabotage my own code. Only thing not here is my machine build, and i know that won't help. Either way i am using a work around at this time while a dev friend helps me debug this further.